# Floating action bar doesn't animate for Snackbar showing up?

Tags: android, android-button, floating-action-button

In my android app, i used the Floating Action Button from the [Clans'](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) 3rd-party library. Like -

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_help_outline"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#009688"
        fab:fab_label="Learn How-To Use"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
```

When my snackbar pops up, the clans fab doesn't animate like the default floating action button from the design library of google.

I saw some proguard rules that would fix the issue. Like:

```
 -keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
 -keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
```

I added those lines to the proguard-rules.pro file, but didn't help at all.
Could anyone suggest what i'm doing wrong?

Any suggestions/advice would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: What layout is your `FloatingActionButton` inside of? Are you using `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: No, i'm using RelativeLayout

Comment: Actually i used FloatingActionMenu with floatingactionbuttons

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you weren't using the stock FloatingActionButton.

Comment: I updated my answer to work with the library you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The default animation you're thinking of is provided by [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and its companion `Behavior` class.

> Behaviors may be used to implement a variety of interactions and additional layout modifications ranging from sliding drawers and panels to swipe-dismissable elements and buttons that stick to other elements as they move and animate.

You need to make two changes. First, you should wrap your `RelativeLayout` with a `CoordinatorLayout` and move your `FloatingActionButton` out of the `RelativeLayout` so that it is a direct descendant of the `CoordinatorLayout`. Your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ... your RelativeLayout here

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.stackoverflow.MyBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Next, you have to create the `MyBehavior` class. I basically just took the design library's `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class and stripped out everything that wasn't strictly necessary. Here's what's left:

```
public class MyBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    public MyBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp) {
        if (lp.dodgeInsetEdges == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
            lp.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, int layoutDirection) {
        parent.onLayoutChild(child, layoutDirection);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getInsetDodgeRect(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, Rect rect) {
        rect.set(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getRight(), child.getBottom());
        return true;
    }
}
```

With those in place, I get the animation you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: After adding the class how can i make use of it?

Comment: @Asif-UlIslamAkash Add `app:layout_behavior` to the FAB and provide the fully-qualified class name (i.e. with the package). In my example, the `MyBehavior` class is in the `com.example.stackoverflow` package, so the attribute is `app:layout_behavior="com.example.stackoverflow.MyBehavior"`